# Search multiple headings(Columns) in other sheet, copy data and paste in main file

Tags: excel, vba

I need a VBA code for a button which when clicked browse for other excel file, search for specific sheet named “Farmer History” in it. In this sheet it looks for A1 complete row and search heading “Crop Area” and copy this column data to main file(where button embedded) in sheet named “Berkhund” at F Column below last cell is used.

The same to be done for other 2 columns too i.e

Looks for “Target Qty” in first row at same sheet “Farmer History” and paste in main file sheet “Berkhund” at R Column below last cell is used

Looks for “Commulative Sold” in first row at same sheet “Farmer History” and paste in main file sheet “Berkhund” at S Column below last cell is used.Code which i tried is given below but it cannot BROWSE for file, search and paste back in main file:

```
Sub copycroparea()
Dim sh As Worksheet, fn As Range
Set sh = Sheets("Farmer History")
Set fn = sh.Rows(1).Find("  Crop Area", , xlValues, xlWhole)
If Not fn Is Nothing Then
  fn.Offset(1).Resize(sh.Cells(Rows.Count, fn.Column).End(xlUp).Row, 1).Copy 
  Sheets("Berkhund").Range("F13")
Else
    MsgBox "Crop area Not Found!"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

End Sub

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with complex formulas or code you are trying to develop. You can familiarize yourself with this site by taking the [2-minute tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you my friend...I have added the code in my post which i tried but it is fixed and cannot BROWSE for file, also it is not dynamic.

Comment: Please Open my Question

Comment: Until (and if) others vote to open it, a method that will help you is the `Application.GetOpenFilename` method.  You can filter for just Excel files, and select the one's you want to open (or, if you know which might hold the desired worksheet, iterate through the entire list and check them).

Comment: Exactly but i don't know how to do this, can you please help me in this. As i want to search and copy other columns too as mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Concepts/Getting-Started/using-arrays) with the 3 search terms and target coumns and use them in a loop.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub copycroparea()

    Const RESULT = "Sheet2" '"Berkhund"
    Const SOURCE = "Farmer History"

    Dim term(3) As Variant
    term(1) = Array("Crop Area", 6) 'F
    term(2) = Array("Target Qty", 18) 'R
    term(3) = Array("Commulative Sold", 19) 'S

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim wbSearch As Workbook, wsSearch As Worksheet
    Dim iTargetRow As Long, iLastRow As Long, sFilename As String

    ' search for file
    sFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx; *.xlsm),*.xlsx;*.xlsm")
    If Len(sFilename) = 0 Or sFilename = "False" Then
        MsgBox "No file selected ", vbCritical
    End If
    'Debug.Print sFilename

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(RESULT)

    Set wbSearch = Workbooks.Open(sFilename, False, True) ' no links update, read only
    Set wsSearch = wbSearch.Sheets(SOURCE)

    Dim i As Integer, sTerm As String, iCol As Integer, msg As String
    Dim rng As Range, rngTarget As Range

    For i = 1 To UBound(term)

        sTerm = term(i)(0)
        iCol = term(i)(1)
        'Debug.Print i, sTerm, iCol

        Set rng = wsSearch.Rows(1).Find(sTerm, , xlValues, xlPart)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then

            ' Destination for copy on main file
            Set rngTarget = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

            ' find extent of data
            iLastRow = wsSearch.Cells(Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            'Debug.Print rngTarget.Address, iLastRow

            ' copy
            rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(iLastRow, 1).Copy rngTarget

            msg = msg & sTerm & " found at " & rng.Address & vbCr
        Else
            msg = msg & sTerm & "not found" & vbCr
        End If

    Next
    wbSearch.Close False

    MsgBox msg, vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: --Thank you so much-- works like charm-- Once again thank you for your time..:)